# Detecting absolute finger positions on trackpad

Tags: ubuntu, driver, trackpad

I'm on a [13" MacBook Pro (model 7,1. Mid-2010)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP583) and I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Essentially what I'm trying to do is make a program that invokes the right-click menu when a user clicks the bottom right corner of the Mac trackpad.

The main issue here is detecting where exactly the user's position on the trackpad *is*. Of course, this is rather easy to do in OSX using `NSTouch`:

```c
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseBegan inView:self];
    for(NSTouch *touch in touches) {
        NSPoint normalizedPosition = touch.normalizedPosition;

        //points inside `normalizedPosition`
        //top center: (.5, 1), bottom left: (1, 0)
    }
}
```

However, the issue is doing the same thing within Ubuntu (any programming language is fine to be honest). Now, I've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573276/know-the-position-of-the-finger-in-the-trackpad-under-mac-os-x), however, because I've already figured out how to do it within OSX, I don't see this question as relevant. I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377090/get-finger-position-on-touchpad) post, however, I'm not looking for a universal, standardized way to detect absolute finger position. Honestly, I'd be happy to get Ubuntu detecting finger positions *only* for Mac-made trackpads. Saw [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239823/use-laptop-trackpad-as-graphics-tablet) also, but the answerer (while he does a great summary) seems to be speaking more universal-wise.

Would anyone know how to get something like the `normalizedPosition` attribute on the [NSTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) within Ubuntu (or a programming language which compiles on Ubuntu)?

Comment: So does this actually have anything to do with Obj-C and Cocoa or is the Obj-C just a "this is how I do it in OS X" thing and otherwise has no relevancy? You're probably going to get mostly the wrong people looking at this post, if so, since you've effectively marked it as a question about Obj-C.

Comment: @nil Well, it applies to people who know Obj-C and may have something to say about what I'm asking. It also would apply to those who could do this in Obj-C on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [mtdev](http://bitmath.org/code/mtdev/) library. Start off with [evtest](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) to figure out what input device and information *from* the input device you need, then use the mtdev library to access it from C.

Another great library to do what I was originally trying to do (i.e., create a zone on the trackpad which would invoke a right-click menu up) is the [mtrack](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack) library (to save some work). It also has examples for accessing information from mtdev if you want to go hunting through the code.