# Finger position on Apple Trackpad with Electron

Tags: macos, electron

I'm trying to create an Electron app that enables the user to draw on the trackpad. Since using only your finger on the trackpad is a a lot more intuitive and precise than requiring the user to actually press down on the trackpad, I'd like to include this functionality. Is there an API available that I can use to get the absolute finger position on Apple's trackpad in Electron?

This is a good example of something I'm aiming to implement: http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/04/sign-documents-trackpad-preview-mac-os-x/

Comment: This might be a stupid question -- how is trackpad position any different from mouse position? Would grabbing the mouse position and drawing it to a canvas fit your use case?

Comment: @ccnokes no because if you lift your finger and press it down further to the left of the trackpad, the mouse position hasn't changed. The absolute trackpad position has.

Comment: Could the down voter explain themselves?

Comment: Hey! Did you find something? I'm looking for exactly the same

Comment: @GonzaloSolera Unfortunately not...

Comment: yall i found this, hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573276/know-the-position-of-the-finger-in-the-trackpad-under-mac-os-x

Comment: it will be hard though, if you guys are still interested