# SwiftUI: Detect finger position on Mac trackpad

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

I'm making a SwiftUI app for macOS and I'd like to use the trackpad as an (x, y) input by detecting the position of the user's fingers. I wanna be able to detect multiple fingers that are *resting* on the trackpad (not dragging). How do I do that?

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573276/know-the-position-of-the-finger-in-the-trackpad-under-mac-os-x) has been asked before, but I'm asking again because that was from nearly 10 years ago, the answers are all in Obj-C (one in Swift 3), and I'm wondering if there's an updated methodology. Most importantly, I've no clue how to implement the Obj-C code into my SwiftUI app so if there isn't any updated methodology, I'd appreciate if someone could just explain how to implement the old Obj-C code.

To demonstrate what I mean, this [video demo](https://youtu.be/b_4phGHH3qg) of the AudioSwift app does exactly what I want. macOS itself also uses this for [hand-writing Chinese](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/chinese-input-method/use-trackpad-handwriting-scim27935/mac) (although I don't need to recognize characters).

Comment: I'm quite a newbie, and I know this is a complicated task, so I'd really appreciate if someone could explain simply with sample code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! This is a pretty broad question - touches lot of topics (how to mix Objective-C & Swift, how to use AppKit inside SwiftUI, ...). As a first thing, please, visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and read how to ask and what you can ask for. It's also important to include at least some code ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to show others that you really tried to solve it. I did post an answer for you just to demonstrate how broad and complex this question is.

Comment: @zrzka thanks so much for the detailed reply! Sorry about the question, I’ll be careful next time.

Comment: you're welcome. Feel free to ask (under the answer) if there's anything unclear and needs more explanation. (Interesting, I can't mention you, hmm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Always split your task into smaller ones and do them one by one. Ask in the same way and avoid broad questions touching lot of topics.

### Goal

- Track pad view (gray rectangle)
- Circles on top of it showing fingers physical position

[image]

### Step 1 - AppKit

- SwiftUI doesn't provide all the required information
- AppKit & [`NSTouch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouch) does - [`normalizedPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouch/1534031-normalizedposition).

First step is to create a simple `AppKitTouchesView` forwarding required touches via a delegate.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

protocol AppKitTouchesViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    // Provides `.touching` touches only.
    func touchesView(_ view: AppKitTouchesView, didUpdateTouchingTouches touches: Set<NSTouch>)
}

final class AppKitTouchesView: NSView {
    weak var delegate: AppKitTouchesViewDelegate?

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        // We're interested in `.indirect` touches only.
        allowedTouchTypes = [.indirect]
        // We'd like to receive resting touches as well.
        wantsRestingTouches = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func handleTouches(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Get all `.touching` touches only (includes `.began`, `.moved` & `.stationary`).
        let touches = event.touches(matching: .touching, in: self)
        // Forward them via delegate.
        delegate?.touchesView(self, didUpdateTouchingTouches: touches)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }
}
```

### Step 2 - Simplified touch structure

Second step is to create a simple custom `Touch` structure which holds all the required information only and is SwiftUI compatible (not flipped `y`).

```swift
struct Touch: Identifiable {
    // `Identifiable` -> `id` is required for `ForEach` (see below).
    let id: Int
    // Normalized touch X position on a device (0.0 - 1.0).
    let normalizedX: CGFloat
    // Normalized touch Y position on a device (0.0 - 1.0).
    let normalizedY: CGFloat

    init(_ nsTouch: NSTouch) {
        self.normalizedX = nsTouch.normalizedPosition.x
        // `NSTouch.normalizedPosition.y` is flipped -> 0.0 means bottom. But the
        // `Touch` structure is meants to be used with the SwiftUI -> flip it.
        self.normalizedY = 1.0 - nsTouch.normalizedPosition.y
        self.id = nsTouch.hash
    }
}
```

### Step 3 - Wrap it for the SwiftUI

- [`NSViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewrepresentable) documentation
- [`Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) documentation

Third step is to create a SwiftUI view wrapping our AppKit `AppKitTouchesView` view.

```swift
struct TouchesView: NSViewRepresentable {
    // Up to date list of touching touches.
    @Binding var touches: [Touch]

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AppKitTouchesView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AppKitTouchesView {
        let view = AppKitTouchesView()
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, AppKitTouchesViewDelegate {
        let parent: TouchesView

        init(_ view: TouchesView) {
            self.parent = view
        }

        func touchesView(_ view: AppKitTouchesView, didUpdateTouchingTouches touches: Set<NSTouch>) {
            parent.touches = touches.map(Touch.init)
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 4 - Make a `TrackPadView`

Fourth step is to create a `TrackPadView` which internally does use our
`TouchesView` and draws circles on it representing physical location of fingers.

```swift
struct TrackPadView: View {
    private let touchViewSize: CGFloat = 20

    @State var touches: [Touch] = []

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                TouchesView(touches: self.$touches)

                ForEach(self.touches) { touch in
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .frame(width: self.touchViewSize, height: self.touchViewSize)
                        .offset(
                            x: proxy.size.width * touch.normalizedX - self.touchViewSize / 2.0,
                            y: proxy.size.height * touch.normalizedY - self.touchViewSize / 2.0
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 5 - Use it in the main `ContentView`

Fifth step is to use it in our main view with some aspect ratio which is close to the real trackpad aspect ratio.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TrackPadView()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .aspectRatio(1.6, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

### Complete project

- Open Xcode
- Create a new project (macOS App & Swift & SwiftUI)
- Copy & paste `ContentView.swift` from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zrzka/224a18517649247a5867fbe65dbd5ae0)

Comment: thanks again for your time, your solution works great. I was wondering, is it possible to "take over" the mouse cursor, such that system gestures (like 4 finger swipe) are disabled and the app can receive touches even if the cursor doesn't start off hovering over `TrackpadView`? If there are any resources you can point me to, I'd be really grateful! (edit: weird, I can't mention you either)

Comment: @qitianshi I'm sorry, but I don't know - didn't try to _take over_ of the trackpad to use it exclusively in my app only. Also I don't know if it's even possible. Probably a good candidate for another question.

Comment: I tried your code and modified it because I only need one touch event then  put it in my SwiftUI code, I got error about the compiler cannot type check expression in reasonable time. After I put TouchView in my own SwiftUI View code.